# How to sort files in vifm by time?

Tags: vifm

Is there any way to sort the files in vifm by time?
Like `ls -t` in bash?

I need to copy the last 4 downloaded files in vifm. Therefore I need to find a way to sort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use "*:sort*" and it opens the menu to decide how to sort. You can press the desired letter to sort directly or you can select the sorting criteria by arrows. And use the left arrow to choose increasing or decreasing sorting. I'm still studying how to use it in a more efficient way but it works.
Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thank for your answer. Actually one can get the same result by pressing the shift + s on the keyboard

Comment: how to put that into `.vifmrc` ?

Answer (score 0):

You hit Esc and then type `:set sort=-mtime`